# How long are OpenID association handles?

Tags: database-design, openid, dotnetopenauth

I'm building an implementation of `DotNetOpenID.RelyingParty.IRelyingPartyApplicationStore` backed by the database behind my web site.

There will be a table of open associations, keyed on the OP URL and the association "handle".

I can't find anything online suggesting how long these handles are in practice, and I am having trouble even figuring out where in the DotNetOpenID code they are generated.

How wide should I make the database field?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Appendix D. Limits](http://openid.net/specs/openid-authentication-1_1.html#limits) of the **[OpenID 1.1 Specification](http://openid.net/specs/openid-authentication-1_1.html)** says:

> assoc_handle: **255 characters** or less, and consist only of ASCII characters in the range 33-126 inclusive (ie printable non-whitespace characters).

[Section 8.2.1. Common Response Parameters](http://openid.net/specs/openid-authentication-2_0.html#anchor20) of the **[OpenID 2.0 Specification](http://openid.net/specs/openid-authentication-2_0.html)** says:

> assoc_handle: [...] A string **255 characters** or less in length. It MUST consist only of ASCII characters in the range 33-126 inclusive (printable non-whitespace characters).

Answer (score 1):

There is no association handle length limit in the OpenID spec, so there unfortunately are no guarantees.  However, Yahoo has the longest association handles I've seen, probably because they encrypt the secret itself into the handle, so there probably isn't any reason for handles to be much longer than that.  Yahoo's handles are ~140 characters in length.  I would allow for 250 characters.

Comment: Sounds good, thanks. I'm glad I asked, the test account I was playing with was on myopenid.com and the handle was a fair bit shorter.